# I have a issue with a Calendar View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, calendarview

I am developing an Android application that uses a `CalendarView`. 
I'm try the app on Android phone that has a `5.0.1 version` and with no problem. But when I try with other version `than 5.0.`1, there are some problems:

1. When a click another date on my calendar not fire any events.
2. When I open the activity with the calendar, the date on calendar is wrong.

Why?

**my code like below:**

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() { 
  @Override 
  public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) { 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String selectedDate = sdf.format(new Date(calendarView.getDate()));
    // DoSomethings... 
  }
});
```

Comment: Put your code here.

Comment: calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String selectedDate = sdf.format(new Date(calendarView.getDate()));

          //DoSomethings...

        }
    });

Comment: What do you mean the date is wrong, What date do you want? Please be more specific

Comment: The date is not of the current day, but the week ago